# CKEDITOR - install Coops plugin in CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor

I have a problem to install `COOPS` plugin for `CKEDITOR`.
With `CKBuiled`, I create a CKE with coops plugin, and after I was upload the CKE app on my web server, I set in the `config.js` file of CKE folder the proprietes are indicated in the documentation like `readonly = true` and the serverUrl, but the plugin not start when I navigate to a sample of CKE.

I think, it is the `serverUrl` VALUE is false, I set it to `"/files"` (I can see that in the coops-demo on github).

Someone can help me please ?
Code :

```html
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2015, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
 config.language = 'fr';
 // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
config.extraPlugins = 'coops';
config.extraPlugins = 'change';
config.extraPlugins = 'coops-connector';
config.extraPlugins = 'coops-dmp';
config.extraPlugins = 'coops-cursors';
config.readOnly = true;
coops: {
  serverUrl: '/files/';
}  

};
```

Comment: paste the code you tried in your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't examined the details of your sample, but check the documentation of [`config.extraPlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins). You should add all `extraPlugins` values in one declaration, otherwise you are simply overwriting one `config.extraPlugins` setting with another instead of extending it.

So:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'coops,change,coops-connector,coops-dmp,coops-cursors';
```

Comment: Yes, i replace the configuration as same as You said but it doesn t change anything for the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link...

https://github.com/foyt/coops-ckplugins

This one is helpful for how to do this.

And you must add url in

```
  server-url:'url';
```

port.Not just add local File Structure..

EX:

```
  server-url:'localhost:8080/ckeditor/sample/';
```